# Are there any all-in-one packages that help install wamp on a production server?

Tags: networking, wamp

I need to install amp on a windows2003 production server. I'd like, if possible, an integrated install/management tool so I don't have to install/integrate the components of amp separately. Those that I've found are 'development' servers. Are there any packages out there that install amp in a production ready (locked down state)?

I'm aware of LAMP... Windows, since we have IIS apps already and we've paid for this box, is a requirement. I'll take care of all the other hangups. I just want a simple way to install, integrate, and manage AMP.

Comment: A couple points: * If you want to install apache on windows server to serve up web traffic, you must first make sure that the native IIS is disabled. You can't have two apps listening on the same port.
* IIS is getting pretty good at serving up PHP. WIMP is becoming more and more popular compared to WAMP. That is especially true of Server 2008/IIS7. It does still apply to 2003/IIS6, but it's harder to do.

Comment: you could try VMware, there are plenty of applicances preinstalled, then you can run your old IIS apps and Apache ones o port 80 of 2 virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any all-in one packages that are up to date and 'designed' for production. You just can't trust the default installs to be secure on whats out there.

I ended up just doing this manually. It wasn't painful though. Each component's install procedure was documented reasonably well. Took me about 3.5hrs. A nice side effect of the involved setup was that it gave me a much better understanding of each component's dependencies and the ways in which they touch. In hind sight I should have done it manually from the start.

Note: make sure you read the comments below each component's documentation pages. Some contain valuable corrections to the install process.

Comment: Exactly. the 'click setup.exe and its all done for you' doesn't save you any time as you still need to knw what's going on. Kudos for taking the trouble to install it all 'properly', now you'll be far better at managing it too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure running WAMP as a production server is a good idea. I use wamp to stage proyects and then I move them to a Linux server.
You can try any of this solutions:
http://www.uniformserver.com/
Some people state that they are [working fine](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3421092.htm) with [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/), but again, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp is quite popular, i just don't know how "production level" it is:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Without wanting to sound elite: For "real" production Environments, it's possibly not a bad idea to setup and configure the components individually, but this requires some deeper knowledge than "hit setup and run".

Answer (score 0):

Since the time this question was asked Zend has released [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/products/server/).

> Zend Server is a complete,
>   enterprise-ready Web Application
>   Server for running and managing PHP
>   applications that require a high level
>   of reliability, performance and
>   security.

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't appear to be any all-in one packages that are up to date and 'designed' for production. You just can't trust the default installs to be secure on whats out there.

[WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) is a commercial WAMP package that is specifically designed for production use (which I use).

I don't think that when this question was asked there was a viable solution for the above.